# C++ time_t to std::string for a specific time zone

Tags: c++, time, posix

In a Linux environment working in C++, I need to convert a time_t value into an English string representation for various time zones. e.g. 1305750080 -> "2011-05-18 13:21:20 PST". I am able to use gmtime() or localtime() combined with strftime() to generate strings for GMT and my local timezone. How would I select an alternative time zone?

Comment: I have retagged this given that the accepted answer is calling a function not in the C++ Standard Library; rather in the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with [tzset](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tzset.html).

```
setenv("TZ", "EST5EDT", 1);
tzset();
```

Answer (score 4):

[`gmtime()` reference link here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/gmtime/) has an example showing a very simple way of applying time zone offsets.  Naturally you could create a class with an enum or something and come up with something a little nicer.

Alternately [`boost::date_time`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time.html) has a pretty extensive implementation that works on linux and windows.

Comment: I found that reference, but won't that cause problems if the date wraps around?

Comment: @JoshG: Yes, the simple example only handles the time, not the date, and doesn't handle timezones (such as India's) with a fractional offset from UTC. I'd probably use boost too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `putenv` to change the `TZ` environment variable to whatever timezone you want and then use `localtime` or preferably `localtime_r`. You can use `getenv` to cache off the old copy if needed.